# Creating a pointcut in Aspectj for each Junit test in a testsuite

Tags: java, junit, aop, aspectj

Hello Im having trouble integrating AspectJ with Junit testing.

I need to get a different log for each test in a testsuite. So I need to know in my aspect when a new test case is being run and when did it finished. How can I define such point cut?

The following pointcut is not working for me, its just being entered once.

```
pointcut testIsAboutToBegin()
: execution (* *.test(..));
```

Comment: Why use an aspect if you could use with JUnit4 @Before or the pendant in JUnit3 by using a method setUp()?

Comment: Because I'm tracing the method calls of each test case with an aspect, and I need to know when to start a new trace.

Comment: Okay, but you maybe could also trigger starting a new trace in a tearDown() method (or annotated with @After in JUnit4).

Comment: I just solved, my problem was with something else, the pointcut was good.

Comment: @Nicolas If the question is irrelevant and doesn't describe actual problem, update or delete it please to doesn't look as an open issue

Comment: Please, delete this question - it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an around advice?

```
pointcut aroundTest(): 
    execution(public void test*(..));

  void around() throws Exception: aroundTest() {
     LOG.info("start");
     proceed();
     LOG.info("stop");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should to use before() and after() for this purpose, try this:

```
before () : testIsAboutToBegin() {
    System.out.println("starting test ... ");
}

after () : testIsAboutToBegin() {
    System.out.println("ending test ... ");
}


//for GetJUnit 4.x
pointcut testJUnit4xIsAboutToBegin() : execution(@Test * *(..))

pointcut testIsAboutToBegin() : execution (* *.test*(..));
```